# ***TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Im moving variables from my python program to an excel file. The variable (TDU_item_description) is the combination of user inputs. What im having a problem with is incrementing the rows so that each variable isnt writing over the previous entry.

```
i = 2

while True:

TDU_to_excel = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 2)

TDU_to_excel.value = TDU_item_description

i += 1
```

---

After running the program I get this error message:

```
TDU_to_excel = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 2)

if row < 1 or column < 1:
```

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

***Im not sure what to convert to `str` or `int` so that they are comparing apples to apples***

Answer (score 0):

```
if int(row) < 1 or int(column) < 1:
```

That should do the trick

Comment: What you suggested isnt part of my code. That only shows up in the error message.  Everything under "After running the program i get this error message" is part of the error. I should have been more clear there, im sorry about that.       Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about saving as CSV and opening in Excel? This is the standard for 'moving variables from my python program to an excel file.'

```
import pandas as pd
df = ..
df.to_csv('from-python.csv')
```

Excel: File -> Open 'from-python.csv'